# Page views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, statistics

I am not sure what is the best way to deal with this. I want to display page views and user views (How many unique users viewed a page).

Is there a plugin for this?

login_count is of course easy to check though. Just not sure about views. Google Analytics does the job well but I don't know whether it's to good to go through analytics integration.

Any help? Thanks. Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend this gem: [Impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: sure. but he asked for a plugin. You can probably make the same comment on hundreds of reply all over this portal, if you have time to kill.

Answer (score 2):

there is a plugin called [railstat](http://github.com/lmanolov/railstat) i used it and it works.  you may need to update it to the latest and greatest rails however.  even if you look at their code you'll see some good examples of how to do it.