# count the times that a webservice is consumed and save it into db in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services

I need count the times that a webservice is consumed, take this number and save it in the database to generate a report, 
I need an idea of ​​how to do it.
I already investigated but I did not find anything useful

Comment: Do you mean you want to count how many times your application was requested?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295026/is-there-a-super-simple-way-to-record-report-page-views-in-rails-2-3-x)?

Comment: @AntonTkachov the web service is consumed from movil app, but the web service in provided from a web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you'd want to do something like this in memory as an attribute on a singleton instance.  Alternatively you could write to an access logfile or database table and count the entries when you generate a report.

Here's a good writeup on the singleton approach: http://konrad-reiche.com/posts/singleton-active-record-charade.html