# hit count gem for rails 3.2 and mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, impressions

I am seeing this gem:

https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist and [simple hit counter for page views in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815713/simple-hit-counter-for-page-views-in-rails)

but It have not support for mongodb and mongoid.

**Is there some gem as impressionist with support for mongoid?**

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to fork and adapt it to mongodb

Comment: Thank you, but I have opened a issue in https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/issues/34 and only support mongomapper