# Is there a Rails Gem for Page Stats?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, statistics, rubygems

I'm allowing users to create sites within my application, and I want to provide simple stats to them like the number of page views. Is there a Rails gem that I can implement to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815713/simple-hit-counter-for-page-views-in-rails

Answer (score 2):

Check this similar question [simple hit counter for page views in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815713/simple-hit-counter-for-page-views-in-rails). Based on the answer to the mentioned question, a gem named [impressionist](http://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) was created by John McAliley. The gem is Rails 3 ready, so you can include it in your app directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the [StatsMix gem](http://www.statsmix.com/developers). You can use it to track any action or event in your application. Disclaimer: I'm the founder and it's a subscription based (paid) service. We do have a free developer plan though and have the abilty to embed charts and dashboards to easily allow for providing stats to your users.

Comment: Could someone let me know why this would have been downvoted? I'm not involved w/ the company anymore, but honestly curious why this didn't effectively answer the above question. Just because it's a gem that works for a commercial service (even though there's a completely free version), doesn't mean it doesn't solve the stated problem.