# Rails model: saving works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Rails model for a Recipe.
It has an attribute, views, which counts how many times it has been viewed.

In the show action of my controller, I fetch the model object normally:

```
@recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
```

Then I increase the view count and save:

```
@recipe.views = @recipe.views + 1
@recipe.save
```

This works without a hitch locally, but on Heroku, the save apparently doesn't happen.
No errors are thrown.

I can run this exact same code in the rails console on Heroku, and then it works.

The only way I can get it to work, is setting

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

in environmenst/production.rb

This is obvously not what I want, but I'm stumped about how to go from here.

I'm running Rails 3.2.8, Ruby 1.9.3 on the Cedar stack, using Postgresql 9.1 in both development and on production.

Comment: Just to clean up the code, you could use `@recipe.increment!(:views)` for your counter (also the ! bang will throw any errors). What db are you using?

Comment: It's postgresql 9.1 both locally and on Heroku. I have a strong feeling it's some sort of caching problem (the action not even being hit on Heroku). Still, I wonder why cache_classes = false makes it work. If I set it to back to true, save stops working.

Comment: No errors are thrown, but do you see any hints in the logs?

Comment: Why not use the impressionist gem, its much easier https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist and an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815713/simple-hit-counter-for-page-views-in-rails

Comment: +1 for admitting the mistake :)

Comment: @Azzar, please consider entering your solution as an answer and then marking it as the answer. That way this will not show as an unresolved question.

Comment: +1 Tass, Please mark this as closed.

Comment: @Azzar - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your "mistake". I view this post and realized I had the same issue and it saves me potentially many hours of banging my head on the wall.. ha

Answer (score 6):

FWIW to future searchers looking for their own solution, Benjamin Tan's answer (in comments) of `heroku restart` was what worked for me when I had a similar problem.

Comment: Oh hell! I can't believe I wasted so much time without trying this!

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answer from the edited question body in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> **UPDATE: Fixed**
>
> Turns out I had a file with another older definition of the controller in the app/controllers directory.

~ answer per [Azzar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1651759/azzar)