# Want to count number of visits on my blogs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to count the number of visits on my blog? Can someone please suggest the overall method to implement this feature?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815713/simple-hit-counter-for-page-views-in-rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just an idea. You can add a `count_view` column in the database into `blogs` table with default value 0.

And in the show action of BlogsController add the following code

```
def show
 @blog = Blog.where('id = ?', params[:id]).first
 @blog.update_column('count_view', @blog.count_view + 1) if @blog.present?
end
```

You can modify this logic as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [hit counter gem](https://github.com/ivanoblomov/hit_counter) or the [impressionist gem](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an existing (free) analytics solutions if you want to get much more data than the number of times the action was called (please note that if the same user refreshes the browser 5 times, you get 5 hits):

http://www.google.com/analytics/

Using these you can get data like unique visitors, referral URL, locations data, browser, OS, and a lot of different stuff to make informed decisions. There are several other options (paid, free, real time) available as well:

https://mixpanel.com

https://www.kissmetrics.com/