# How to avoid Race Condition and Lock wait timeout updating views of a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, race-condition

Inside a Rails application, users visit a page where I show a popup.
I want to update a record every time users see that popup.

To avoid race condition I use optimistic locking (so I added a field called lock_version in the popups table).

The code is straightforward:

```
# inside pages/show.html.erb
<%= render @popup %>

# and inside the popup partial...
...
<%
  Popup.transaction do
     begin
       popup.update_attributes(:views => popup.views + 1)
     rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError
       retry
     end
  end
%>
```

The problem is that lots of users access the page, and mysql exceeds timeout for locking.

So the website freeze and I get lots of these errors:
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

That's because there are lots of pending requests trying to update the record with an outdated lock_version value.

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [increment_counter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods/increment_counter) because it produce one SQL UPDATE query without locking.

But I think will be better in your case to use any key-value DB like Redis to store and update your popup counter because it can do it faster than SQL DB.

Comment: One approach I'm trying is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815713/simple-hit-counter-for-page-views-in-rails/4817567#4817567 with some customizations. Instead to create multiple records for the same user (my page is accessible previous login), I increment "views" field on a unique record related to the user. It seems to work fine. I'll let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot go with an approach like @maxd noted in their reply, you can utilize an asynchronous library such as [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org) to process these sort of requests (wherein they'll just get backed up in the job queue).

**lib/some_made_up_class.rb**

```
def increment_popup(popup)
  Popup.transaction do
    begin
       popup.update_attributes(:views => popup.views + 1)
     rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError
       retry
     end
  end
end
```

Then, in another piece of code (your controller, a service, or the view (less ideal to put logic in the view layer).

```
SomeMadeUpClass.delay.increment_popup(popup)
# OR you can schedule it
SomeMadeUpClass.delay_for(1.second).increment_popup(popup)
```

This would have the effect of, essentially, queueing up your inserts, while freeing your page and, in theory, helping to reduce the timeouts you're hitting, etc.

While there is certainly more to it than just adding a library (gem) like Sidekiq and the sample code I have here, I think asynchronous libraries/tools will help tremendously.

Comment: Hi craig, take a look at the comment below maxd response. I'm trying a different approach.