# Rails how to sort search results based on popularity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Im working on the search feature for my app and I would like to give users the option for some sorting of viewing the recipes.  Im trying to make a popular feature but Im not entirely sure where to start and if I need to make any modifications to my schema.  Ive read this post http://sorentwo.com/2013/12/30/let-postgres-do-the-work.html and get the jist of what its doing.  My main question is how do I track when a page is viewed and use that in the calculations? And also track views over time?

Also for using things like comments as a weight is it better to count the number of comments dynamically (query the comment table and add them up) or keep a column in the recipe table that gets added to whenever a comment is added?

Comment: if you do go for comments as a weight to have counter_cache to make it more efficient when retrieving the counts of an object.

Comment: Ok, sweet thanks for the point towards counter_cache, I was gonna implement that myself didnt realize there was already a feature.  Any input on how to handle tracking views

Comment: look into this page it might give you what you want with tracking views: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815713/simple-hit-counter-for-page-views-in-rails

Comment: Thanks that will work for what I need, now I just need to work out the equation to take everything into account...but that is just a math problem and doing some reading