# How to track models using ahoy in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, analytics, tracking, ahoy

I integrated `ahoy` well. But my purpose is to track how many times any model show page visited.

Let say i have 2 model `CarModel` and `CarMake`
I want to tract visits like `CarModel.first.visits` and `CarMake.first.visits`

But only solutions find is to hit `ahot.track("model"+car_model.id)` and saves it in events and then I need to query by strings, which is not a generic way.

I want to get visits of any model by `Model.visits`
is `ahoy` support like this?

Comment: Isn't ahoy automatically tracking visits for you? And if you really want to use events, why don't you pass the `car_model.id` as an argument: `ahoy.track("car_model", { model: car_model.id })`?

Comment: Also check out this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815713/simple-hit-counter-for-page-views-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to achieve `Model.visits` for `CarModel` and the same can be done for any other model.

#### Create a Migration

```rb
rails g migration CreateCarModelVisits car_model:references visit:references
```

and associate it with the Ahoy Visit table (**note the Ahoy migration**).

```rb
class CreateVisitable < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :visitables do |t|
      t.references :car_model, foreign_key: true
      t.references :visit, foreign_key: { to_table: :ahoy_visits }

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

#### Associate Models

One-to-many associations can be implemented, to avoid modifications in the Ahoy table I'm simply creating a many-to-many relationship.

```rb
class CarModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :visitables, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :visits, through: :visitables, class_name: 'Ahoy::Visit'
 end

class Visitable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :car_model
  belongs_to :visit, class_name: 'Ahoy::Visit'
end

class Ahoy::Visit < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :visitables, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :car_models, through: :visitables
end
```

#### Track Visits with Model

It can be done via any controller/model `callback`. For controller callback:

```rb
CarModel.first.visits << current_visit
```

#### Access Tracked Visits

```rb
CarModel.first.visits
```